# C# dynamic ExpandoObject Array

Tags: c#

please tell me, how do I get the json like this:

```
    dynamic packet = new ExpandoObject();
    packet.type = "somethink";
    packet.user = 12345;

    packet.nets[0].amout = 123;
    packet.nets[0].lower = 0;
    packet.nets[1].amout = 345;
    packet.nets[1].lower = 1;
    string input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
```

Its not workig, error:
An unhandled exception of type "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" in System.Core.dll

For more information: "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject" does not contain definitions of "nets"

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the `ExpandoObject` who's a dynamic object. The rest of properties should be other `ExpandoObject` instances or regular objects, arrays, collections...

For example:

```
packet.nets = new[] 
{
     new { amount = 123, lower = 0 },
     new { amount = 345, lower = 1 }
}
```

Or:

```
packet.nets = new[]
{
     new Dictionary<string, int> { { "amount", 345 }, { "lower", 0 } },
     new Dictionary<string, int> { { "amount", 123 }, { "lower", 1 } }
}
```

There're many other approaches, including the use of instances of concrete classes.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need create `nets` in `packet` object, like this:

```
packet.nets = new dynamic[2];
```

And initialize the objects in `nets`, if you want with `ExpandoObject too:

```
packet.nets[0] = new ExpandoObject();
packet.nets[1] = new ExpandoObject();
```

Then is done, complete code:

```
dynamic packet = new ExpandoObject();
packet.type = "somethink";
packet.user = 12345;

packet.nets = new dynamic[2];

packet.nets[0] = new ExpandoObject();
packet.nets[0].amout = 123;
packet.nets[0].lower = 0;

packet.nets[1] = new ExpandoObject();
packet.nets[1].amout = 345;
packet.nets[1].lower = 1;            

string input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to declare nets. For example

`packet.nets = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();`

Then you'll need to instantiate the instances of nets

`packet.nets[0] = new {amount = 123, lower = 0};`

The result being

```
dynamic packet = new ExpandoObject();
packet.type = "somethink";
packet.user = 12345;

packet.nets = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();
packet.nets[0] = new { amount = 123, lower = 0 };
packet.nets[1] = new { amount = 345, lower = 1 };
```

Comment: Why the values should be `dynamic`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I guess they can be object, same difference. Your code automatic array initiation is probably better than declaring it as a Dictionary anyway. The only thing is you can remove the `object` part, the compiler will assume it. Not sure why you got the downvote, I upvoted.

Comment: Hey, yeah, I've turned the code to get type inference by usage. In my case I would declare values typed as `dynamic` if they should be accessed later. If it's just for serialization, who cares, `object` does the job well too

Comment: About the downvoter... maybe that user pressed the wrong button or who knows ;P